# Building library with imports from another library using NX Monorepo

Tags: tsconfig, monorepo, nrwl, nrwl-nx

Here is the case. I am using Nrwl NX Monorepo. I have 2 libraries: `lib-a` and `lib-b`; both are publishable libraries created via NX.

Now I create a `MyClass.ts` in `lib-a`. Naturally under paths in `workspace/tsconfig.json` > `paths` NX creates an alias to this `lib-a` (`"@workspace/lib-a": ["libs/lib-a/src/index.ts"]`).

So far so good. Now we can use this class anywhere within the workspace/monorepo by importing it via `import { MyClass } from '@workspace/lib-a';`

Unfortunately we can not build `lib-b` which is importing `MyClass`. When we try to do it we get the bellow error. So question is how can we build `lib-b` ?

PS: It seems strange that NX monorepo actually don't support such a common scenario linking 2 publishable libs.

> "error TS6059: File "d:/workspace/libs/lib-a/src/index.ts" is not
> under 'rootDir' "d:\workspace\libs\lib-b\src" rootDir is expected to
> contain all source files"

Comment: it's 2022 and still the same issue lol

Comment: it's 2023 and still I'm getting the same error :(

Comment: @ViranMalaka appreciate if you could share if you have a solution on this

Comment: @Praveen, Thanks for bringing this up. I forgot to update my solution here. did you update your `tsconfig.base.json` file to change the alise to the lib? In my case that was the issue. if so that same alise name should be under the libs/<lib-name>/package.json -> name property.
let me know the comment is not clear, I'll post a new answer.

Comment: None of the answers below have worked for me. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 6):

Try adding

```
"paths": { "@workspace/*": ["dist/libs/*"] }
```

into your tsconfig.lib.json files. This should resolve the problem.

Comment: This is the only good answer

Comment: Did not work for me :(

Answer (score 2):

Don't override "baseUrl" and "paths" in any of child tsconfig!
Put all of your "paths" in tsconfig.base.ts!

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. Not sure it's official, but in my case it's working well.
3 problems should be resolved:

1. TypeScript paths
2. Compiled JS paths
3. Working directory

First. TypeScript paths is resolved by adding "paths" into workspace/tsconfig.lib.json. NX does it automatically while lib gen. Look answer from Radovan Skendzic.

Second. Problem with compiled JS paths very good described here: [Typescript paths not working in an Express project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187115/typescript-paths-not-working-in-an-express-project). So you need to install tsconfig-paths into your workspace:

```
yarn add -D tsconfig-paths
```

Third. Considering nx run [project]:[target] is working in workspace/ directory you should set CWD to libs/lib-b home directory - to find correct tsconfig.json

So, finally, you have the following executor (add this to your lib-b/project.json) that should work:

```
"targets": {
    "start-dev": {
        "executor": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
        "options": {
            "commands": [
                "nodemon -e ts,js --exec ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts"
            ],
            "cwd": "libs/lib-b"
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Command to run:

```
nx run lib-b:start-dev
```

Comment: That works great! How do you use this solution in production?

Comment: Not yet. I've just met this issue during dev - was trying func call btw two libs. StackOverflow is great - I instantly found the same problem from others and fill I'm not alone!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `lib-a` as an implicit dependency of `lib-b`, add the line below into the `libs/lib-b/project.json` file and see what happens:

```
"implicitDependencies": ["lib-a"]
```

Running `nx graph` should show you a graph that should look something like this (do not consider the name of the libraries):

[image]

After that you should be able to build both libraries, I hope it works with you as well.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me. the graph was changed but the import still did not work

Answer (score 1):

adding rootDir to project.json options worked for me

```
"targets": {
"build": {
  "executor": "@nx/js:tsc",
  "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
  "options": {
    "rootDir": ".",
```

Answer (score 0):

nx sets up paths in the tsconfig.base.json so that you can import from your libs within the monorepo without any futher setup.

If your monorepo is called my-monorepo and the lib you want to import from is called my-other-lib then you should be able to do: `import { foo } from '@my-monorepo/my-other-lib';`

See the docs for full info: https://nx.dev/concepts/more-concepts/applications-and-libraries

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the scope of each project through the `'tags'` field in the `project.json` file. This ensures that the typescript does not complain during import, and your problem is resolved. Please pay attention to the following code.

for `lib-a` project edit the `project.json` file like this:

```
{
  // ... more project configuration here
  "tags": ["scope:lib-a"]
}
```

You can find much more information in the [Nx documentation](https://nx.dev/core-features/enforce-module-boundaries#tags)

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me, instead I had to change the angular version in `lib-b`'s `package.json` to version 15:

```json
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0"
  },
```

I generated `lib-b` with an nx schematic and it generated this with version 16, but my `lib-a` was at version 15.0.0. I suspect the problem was not the particular version but that the versions need to match. Updated it manually and the project builds.