# Typescript paths not working in an Express project

Tags: typescript, nodemon, ts-node

I am trying to use TypeScript's paths functionality so that I don't need to use relative imports any more.

Here is my *tsconfig.json* file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/*"],
      "@config/*": ["src/config/*"],
      "@controllers/*": ["src/controllers/*"],
      "@middlewares/*": ["src/middlewares/*"],
      "@models/*": ["src/models/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["src/routes/*"],
      "@types/*": ["src/types/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "firebase-config.json", "webpack.config.js"]
}
```

Here is my *package.json* file:

```
{
  "name": "express-ts-boilerplate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Express Typescript Boilerplate",
  "main": "src/server.js",
  "author": "Sriram R",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/src/app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/app.ts",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "test": "mocha --exit -r ts-node/register src/tests/*.spec.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // Dependencies here
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // Dependencies here
  },
}
```

So now in one of my files, I try `@config/typeConfig` but I just get `cannot find module` error.

Maybe it's because of `nodemon` but it didn't work with `ts-node` too.
How can I get this to work?

Comment: "So now in one of my files". Which file? Where is it located?

Comment: It is located under src folder. The server file where I'm importing config variables.

Comment: Weird. I tried to replicate your problem and it's working fine here. How come you have nodemon src/app.ts?

Comment: Because I'm using nodemon to run during development. That's where I suspect the problem is.

Comment: Shouldn't it be nodemon dist/src/app.js?

Comment: No. That will only work after building the ts files. During testing, I don't want to keep it building every time and nodemon works fine with typescript express projects.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Note: for a working example with *nodemon*, skip to the second section of my answer.

If you mean that once you compiled the files and run the application, the modules are not found, then have a look at this thread: [Module path maps are not resolved in emitted code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866)

> "paths" is designed for use with loaders that allow remapping

Say I have this path in my *tsconfig.json*:

```
"paths": {
      "@config/*": ["src/config/*"]
    }
```

And I require a file using that path in a file

```
import test from '@config/test';
```

Looking into the compiled file, I end up with

```
var test_1 = __importDefault(require("@config/test"));
```

As you can see, paths have not been resolved, it's still @config/test. The same thing will happen when testing your app with *nodemon* and *ts-node*.

In addition, you need to use a Typescript path alias resolver, like for example[tspath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tspath).

> The TypeScript compiler will be able to resolve the paths so this will compile without problems, however the JavaScript output will not be possible to execute by Node nor a Web Browser, why? the reason is simple!
>
> The JavaScript engine does not know anything about the compile time TypeScript configuration.
>
> In order to run your JavaScript code, the path aliases now needs to be made into relative paths again, here is when TSPath comes into play.

---

That being said, if you want to make things work with *nodemon*, the following configuration will do. Beforehand, make sure you installed [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths).

```
npm i tsconfig-paths
```

> Use this to load modules whose location is specified in the paths section of tsconfig.json. Both loading at run-time and via API are supported.
>   (...)
>   If you require this package's **tsconfig-paths/register** module it will read the paths from **tsconfig.json** and **convert node's module loading calls into to physcial file paths** that node can load.

Perfect, we will execute `node` with `-r tsconfig-paths/register` to convert paths into physical file paths and `-r ts-node/register` to execute ts files on the fly and *nodemon* will restart the app upon changes.

In your *package.json*, you need to add this (modify it as needed):

```
    "nodemonConfig": {
          "ignore":
            [
              "**/*.test.ts",
              "**/*.spec.ts",
              ".git",
              "node_modules"
            ],
          "watch": [
            "src"
          ],
          "exec": "node -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register ./src/server.ts",
          "ext": "ts, js"
        },
    "scripts": {
          "dev": "nodemon"
        }
```

Note the added configuration for *nodemon*.

And finally

```
npm run dev
```

And things should be running smoothly.

Comment: so hard to find this. Truely safe me

Answer (score 31):

[jperl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187115/typescript-paths-not-working-in-an-express-project/58226283#58226283) is completely correct.

In case you want a one-line solution:

```
nodemon -e ts,js --exec ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/server.ts
```

Just *remember* to install `tsconfig-paths/register`:

```
npm i -D tsconfig-paths
```

In case instead of requiring `-r tsconfig-paths/register` in a CLI command or an npm script you would like to require it in ts-node configuration, you could do it in `tsconfig.json` as follows:

```json
// in tsconfig.json
{
  // ... other TypeScript configuration
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but you had better mention we have to install `tsconfig-paths`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will edit my answer

Comment: Should it say:

npm i -D tsconfig-paths

instead of

npm i -D tsconfig-paths/register

?

Comment: absolutely true! i will fix it.

Comment: it dos't work for me

Comment: Damn, this is convoluted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my particular case use "[tsc-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias)" these were my steps:

1. Install package `npm install --save-dev tsc-alias`
2. Change the command with which I compile in package.json to `"build": "tsc && tsc-alias"`
3. Modify my tsconfig.json because I did not have the **outDir**, so that it would look like this:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "miniprogram",
      "baseUrl": "miniprogram",
      "paths": {
       "lib / *": ["./lib/*"]
     },
...
}
```

**Note:** If I don't add the **outDir** it gives me the following error: **"compilerOptions.outDir is not set"**

Then when importing it I do:
`import {Util} from "lib/my/path/util";`

Answer (score 2):

**first step.** we need to install tsconfig-paths

`npm i -D tsconfig-paths`

**second step.** Create the **nodemon.json** file in the root path. same level with package.json

**third step.** Copy and paste the code below into the nodemon.json file. In the code, ./src/app.ts This part is an express execution point. Modify it according to your situation.

```
{
  "ignore": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", ".git", "node_modules"],
  "watch": ["src"],
  "exec": "node -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register ./src/app.ts",
  "ext": "ts, js"
}
```

**last step.** write executing script code in the package.json file

```
"script": {
  "dev": "nodemon"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Development**

```
npm i -save-dev tsconfig-paths/register
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
    },   
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  dev: "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts"
}
```

**Build**

```
npm i -save-d ttypescript @zerollup/ts-transform-paths
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
    },   
  }
 "plugins": [
      {
          "transform": "@zerollup/ts-transform-paths",
      }
  ],
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  build: "ttsc -P ./tsconfig.json"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR: delete all .js files

For those who didnt manage the with correct solutions above:

With my project I had 'leftover' .js files created (at some point in the past) under each .ts file.
running `nodemon` (which in turn should use `tsc`) did not overwrite those files, and I kept getting the same require stack errors with `Cannot resolve module`.

Removing all .js files fixed it for me.

Refer to this answer for more information on how to actually do it in a safe(ish) way: [Find (and delete) all files with a specified extension](https://askubuntu.com/a/377442/1090612). make sure you actually review the list of files before deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it didn't work any of the last answers so I had to install [tsx] and create a nodemon.json file with the next configuration

```
npm i tsx
```

```
{
    "ignore": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", ".git", "node_modules"],
    "watch": ["."],
    "exec": "tsx index.ts",
    "ext": "ts, js"
}
```