# Typescript custom path issue - module not found

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

In my express.js typescript project, I've added custom paths to my express tsconfig.json file like this:

[image]

Then I'm importing my files with absolute custom path with no error like this:

[image]

But after building the project with `tsc` command, the import string in my built `.js` file is the exact same string as `.ts` file and my import path mapping is not working.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using both `tsc-alias` and `tsconfig-paths` packages.

`"build": "npx tsc && tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json"`

`"dev": "nodemon -r tsconfig-paths/register index.ts"`

more info: [Typescript paths not working in an Express project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187115/typescript-paths-not-working-in-an-express-project)