# Nx - how to import from another module when building with the tsc executor?

Tags: node.js, typescript, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I have a problem that is similar to the one described in [Building library with imports from another library using NX Monorepo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57046016/building-library-with-imports-from-another-library-using-nx-monorepo).
Using nx monorepo with a node app and a library. The app is built with `@nrwl/js:tsc` (not webpack as it is by default) and then executed using `@nrwl/node:node`. This is what the project.json looks like:

```
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/js:tsc",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "main": "apps/dep/src/main.ts",
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/dep",
        "tsConfig": "apps/dep/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/node:node",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "dep:build"
      }
    },
```

Importing anything from another library causes a problem with the build due to files not being under `rootDir`:

```
import { MyEnum } from '@zorro/types';
```

This I resolved using the advice from the question above, adding the following settings to `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "incremental": false,
    "paths": { "@zorro/*": ["dist/libs/*"] }
  },
```

This made tsc work, but when running with node, I get an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@zorro/types'
```

Can't figure out what needs to be changed in order to properly resolve the path of the library for the compiled `main.js` file.

Comment: Please look [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73132174/1017684). Hope it'll help!

Comment: @LeMa you are a lifesaver! That really did the trick.