# Trouble importing module: Cannot find module its corresponding type declarations. in a monorepo (mx)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

i have a NX workspace, libs compile correctly but on one lib it's having trouble
`libs/business-logic/helpers/src/index.ts:11:15 - error TS6059: File '/Users/Projects/mono/org/libs/business-logic/helpers/src/lib/params.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users//Projects/mono/org/libs/api/data'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

11 export * from './lib/params';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

> NX   Ran target build for project api and 4 task(s) they depend on (7s)

```
✖    1/5 failed
✔    4/5 succeeded [4 read from cache]
```

`
i've read all of [Building library with imports from another library using NX Monorepo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57046016/building-library-with-imports-from-another-library-using-nx-monorepo) and tried them all with  no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the scope of each project through the `'tags'` field in the `project.json` file. This ensures that the typescript does not complain during import, and your problem is resolved. Please pay attention to the following code.

for `business-logic` project edit the project.json file like this:

```
{
  // ... more project configuration here
  "tags": ["scope:business-logic"]
}
```

You can find much more information in the [Nx documentation](https://nx.dev/core-features/enforce-module-boundaries#tags)